# Have to reset the router to get internet speed back to normal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a router that needs to be reset to get the internet speed back to a usable speed. It is a fairly old router (D-LINK DSL 2730B) and it does get quite annoying. There is allot of devices connected, which may affect the speed, but I am sure it shouldn't change upon reboot. I literally reboot every hour or 2 during peek periods. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's broken. This happens all the time, and the reason customer grade routers are as cheap as they are is because noone expects them to last for more than a couple of years. Buy a new one, or better yet, buy a new and more expensive one if you want it to last and stay reliable. I would recommend the [Linksys E1200 Wireless-N300 Router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004T9RR6I), it's a great router for a good price. D-LINK is a brand that I have had nothing but trouble with when it comes to routers.

Of course, if your current router is still within warranty, you could try having it replaced.